# Laravel throwing chunk error with extract-text-webpack-plugin after irrelevant operation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I installed css-loader and vue-style loader. Then decided I don't need them and immediately uninstalled them. Since then Laravel (Mix) started throwing this error on `npm run whatever`

```
Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
at Chunk.get (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:460:9)
at D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compilation.seal (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:881:27)
at hooks.make.callAsync.err (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:17)
at _err0 (eval at create (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
at _addModuleChain (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:749:12)
at processModuleDependencies.err (D:\Host\clients\reservations\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:688:9)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development 
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules -- config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I ran `npm install` again, cleared the cache, did lots of generic things. Also tried reinstalling this plugin. Same error all the time.

My package.json for refference:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "vue": "^2.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
}
```

}

The `dependencies` block items are there since I installed them manually while trying different things.

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install`

Comment: Did that, after several tries I `rm -rf`-ed the whole thing and isntalled it again. After that I found another of my Laravel projects and used it's package json, adding only the crucial dependencies of this project - same exact error everytime.

Comment: I think that you are facing this issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701